# Error while trying to install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, amd-processor

```
System specifications:-
Processor: AMD RYZEN 2200g
Ram: Corsair vengeance 8gb
Motherboard: Asus B450M-K  (am4 architecture)
```

This is a custom build

I built this system to run Linux (Ubuntu) but I wasn't able to do so.
Every time I try to install I run into an error which says `amd-vi completion-wait loop timed out`.

I tried multiple times but ended up with same error and that there were no keyboard or mouse detected though I plugged them into USB 2.0.
I tried using another PC which has `Intel core i3`. I was easily able to install Ubuntu 18 on that and it worked perfectly.

So I took that HDD and plugged it into my PC which did boot up into Ubuntu after a span of time but my keyboard would stop working after login. The mouse never worked.

While I was trying to resolve this issue I faced a new problem when Everytime I would boot my system it showed `invalid file system entering rescue mode`

I really need to use Linux as I need to run `nextcloud` and other services.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is...I needed to update my BIOS